# mixing c and assembly (ARM) subroutine

Tags: c, eclipse, assembly, arm, subroutine

i have to make a surbroutine in two files, i have a problem to build the project, there is an error:

> undefined reference to c

I don't know what happen, i'm trying to send the C[0] memory direction that's why the c=C[0], is it ok? do i have to to it with "i" too?. thank you guys.

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int N = 3;
extern int abs_escalar(int,int,int);
extern int abs(int x){
    if(x<0){
        x=0-x;
    }
    return x;
}
extern int c;
extern int i;
int main() {

    int A[3][3]={{1,2,3},{5,7,3},{1,5,9}};
    int B[3][3]={{3,5,7},{4,2,6},{1,8,3}};
    int C[3];
    c = C[0];
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        C[i] = abs_escalar(A[N][N],B[N][N],N);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

.asm (please ignore the spanish comments)

```
.extern abs;
.extern C;
.extern i;

.global abs_escalar;
.text
abs_escalar:

            ldr r4,=C;
            ldr r5,=i;
            mov r6,#0; //hace la vez de j y de cero en c[i] = 0;
            str r6,[r4,r5,lsl#2];

for:        cmp r6,r2 //r2 es n
            beq finfor
            mul r7,r2,r5 //mult ncolumnas * i
            add r7,r7,r6 //suma para el indice
            ldr r7,[r0,r7,lsl#2] //Cargo el dato de A[i][j]
            push {r0-r2} //guardo la dir de memoria de A , de B y n porque lo voy a necesitar
            mov r0,r7 //envio el dato en r0
            bl abs
            mov r7,r0 //guardo el dato en r0
            pop {r0-r2} //recupero la dir de A
            ldr r8,[r1,r7,lsl#2] //cargo el dato de B[i][j]
            push {r0-r2}
            mov r0,r8
            bl abs
            mov r8,r0
            pop {r0-r2}
            ldr r9,[r4,r5,lsl#2]
            mul r10,r7,r8
            add r9,r9,r10
            add r6,r6,#1 //aumento el indice j
            b for
finfor:     //str r9,[r4,r5,lsl#2] solo enviamos el dato la funcion principal la guarda
            mov r0,r9
            mov pc,lr


            .end
```

Comment: well with N=3 you're off the end of arrays A and B, array indices start at 0

Comment: You only included one file.  Did you look in your map file to see if your compiler adds an underscore to C globals?

Comment: What are all of these `extern`s? Are you sure you understand their meaning?

Comment: @bph do you mean because of "abs_escalar(A[N][N],B[N][N],N)" right? i dind't see it, thank you.

Comment: @SteveKolokowsky i'm sorry i don't know how to generate it, but i added the second file.

Comment: @EugeneSh. the other externs i have to use in the subroutine, i updated the code. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the variable `c` defined? Writing

```
extern int c;
```

only *declares* `c`, you still need to define it somewhere.

Comment: `code extern int c; ...     int C[3];     c = C[0]; `
I though i did it there

Comment: @kriptor That code declares `C` as a local variable, shadowing the global `C`. Please read about C declaration syntax, this site cannot replace a tutorial.

Comment: @kriptor It does however not define `c` or the global `C`.

Comment: ohhh right now i see, i'm sorry, i made this horribles mistakes when i try to mix assembly with c. thank you

Answer (score 1):

`extern int c;`in your c file is lower case and`.extern C;` in your assembly file is upper case, change `extern int c;` to `extern int C;` (of course you'll have to change your `int C[3];` array as well)

Comment: i did it at first, but then i realize that i want to send  the memory address of C[0], that's why i put c variable to got that adrress